# is there Material increment/decrement Button implementation for Android?

Tags: android, material-design

is there by any chance a Material design implementation for increment/decrement button ? [image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4hgj.jpg)

Comment: There isn't . Its just a layout with two button and a text .

Comment: Thank you. I know that it's a just tow buttons with text, but material design offers a better UX/UI for your apps, and their guidelines are the recommended practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but it's quite simple to implement, you only need a linear layout with horizontal orientation, containing a button, a textview and another button.
Have an internal value to count and then associate a callback to your buttons, where you add/substract your counter and update the textview, like this:

```
substractButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  count--;
  countTextView.setText(count);
});
sumButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  count++;
  countTextView.setText(count);
});
```